# Asp.net grid view using datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

here is a small registration form and all i wanna do is when user clicks the button i want to enter the details in the form to grid view by using data-table and sessions

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <center>
        <table>                
            <tr>
                <td>
                    First Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Last Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Location
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtLocation" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Mobile No
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtMobileNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="BtnSave" Text="SAVE" runat="server" onclick="BtnSave_Click"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="BtnCancel" Text="CANCEL" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
    <center>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridDataTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
        <Columns>            
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" >
        <ItemTemplate>            
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>            
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name"></asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location"></asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mobile No"></asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </center>
</div>
</form>
```

and here is my code behind but its not working help me with this

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Bind();
        }

    }
     protected void Bind()
    {
        System.Data.DataTable workTable = new System.Data.DataTable("RegTable");           
        workTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FirstName", typeof(String)));
        workTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("LastName", typeof(String)));
        workTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Location", typeof(String)));
        workTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MobileNo", typeof(Int32)));  
        Session["RegDetails"] = workTable;           
        GridDataTable.DataSource = workTable;
        GridDataTable.DataBind();
    }

    protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = (System.Data.DataTable)Session["RegDetails"];          
        DataRow  dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["FirstName"] = TxtFirstName.Text.ToString();
        dr["LastName"] = TxtLastName.Text.ToString();
        dr["Location"] = TxtLocation.Text.ToString();
        dr["MobileNo"] = TxtMobileNo.Text;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        Session["RegDetails"] = dt;            
        GridDataTable.DataSource = dt;
        GridDataTable.DataBind();         


    }
```

Comment: _"its not working"_ Perhaps you can specify the problem a little bit. Btw, why do you add a  `DataColumn` that has no name and type? `workTable.Columns.Add(workCol);`

Comment: i think each column had its type and name. what's wrong in it

Comment: What is exactly not working here? It maybe the session, try use `ViewState`. This line `DataColumn workCol = new DataColumn();` what are you doing with it? why you are adding an empty row here `DataRow dr = workTable.NewRow();`?

Comment: @Vivekh: I have posted the `DataColumn` that has no name and type, it is `workCol`. You have initialized it in this way: `DataColumn workCol = new DataColumn();`.

Comment: got it havent add itemtemplate to gridview. any way thanks

Comment: Then either delete your question or add your comment as answer and accept it even if I doubt that it will ever help any future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is your `GridView` markup. Your code behind part is working as copied & verified the same.

As seen you have not bounded data to any fields like `<asp:label>` etc.. in your `<asp:TemplateField>`.

Morever, you are missing `<ItemTemplates>` in some `<asp:TemplateFields>`.

So set your GridView Markup as:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridDataTable" runat="server" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
 <Columns>            
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" >
        <ItemTemplate> 
           <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("FirstName")%>' runat="server">   
           </asp:Label>                
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>            
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">
       <ItemTemplate> 
           <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("LastName")%>' runat="server">   
           </asp:Label>                
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location">
       <ItemTemplate> 
           <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("Location")%>' runat="server">   
            </asp:Label>                
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mobile No">
        <ItemTemplate> 
           <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("MobileNo")%>' runat="server">   
           </asp:Label>                
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score -1):

First you insert the data into database and then retrieve it through gridview....

Comment: this is not an answer.